# How to work with this singly linked list?

Tags: c++, c, struct, linked-list

I have a strange linked list (code is not mine):

```
struct _P_NEXT
{ P_NEXT* p_el; };
```

As you can see, there is no data field. However, the list must contain complex structures.
For illustration, I give a method of adding an item to the end of the list:

```
void in_tail(P_NEXT* head_list, P_NEXT* el_list) {

    el_list->p_el = NULL;

    P_NEXT* el;
    el = head_list->p_el;

    if (el) {
        while (el->p_el)
            el = el->p_el;

        (el->p_el) = el_list;
    }
    else {
        head_list->p_el = el_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: This list doesn't seem very useful. Maybe you should ask the person who wrote the code.

Comment: what exactly is your qustion? what do you need?

Comment: The struct is named `_P_NEXT` while the pointer in the struct is of type `P_NEXT*`. What's the connection? Is it maybe more than just `typedef`?

Comment: C or C++? The code provided is C. Why did you tagged the question with C++?

Comment: Maybe you can use type conversion somehow? Pointers?

Comment: see https://www.data-structures-in-practice.com/intrusive-linked-lists/

Comment: If there's no documentation, you should try to find some examples where this list is actually used. Maybe it works similar to the linked-list implementation in the linux kernel, which also only defines the prev/next pointers, but no data pointer or anything like that. In such an implementation, what you're expected to do is probably to add a `struct _P_NEXT` to your own struct which defines the actual data to be stored in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of structure is usually used as [intrusive list](https://www.data-structures-in-practice.com/intrusive-linked-lists/)

this is usually useful in C where there is no type polymorphism and but you want to have common function for maintenance and utility.

Usage example:

```
struct node {
    struct _P_NEXT list; // must be the first member of the structure
    int data; 
    // and so on ....
};
```

and you can still use `in_tail` with the defined `struct node` above, because the way the stucture is layed out in memory, the address of an `node` would be the same address of its first member (a `struct _P_NEXT`).

example:

```
struct node head;
head.list.p_el = NULL;
// init head data
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    struct node node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // set node data
    in_tail((struct _P_NEXT*)&head, (struct _P_NEXT*)node);
}
```

You can have a cleanup list function written the same way:

```
void cleanup_list(P_NEXT* list) {
    while(list !=NULL) {
        P_NEXT* current = list;
        list = current -> p_el;
        free(current);
    }
}
```

and invoked the same:

```
cleanup_list((P_NEXT*)head.list.p_el);
```

Comment: Note that, depending on the implementation, it might actually not be necessary to have `struct _P_NEXT` as the first member. The linux linked-list implementation for instance provides a handful of macros, which make it possible to have this member anywhere in a struct (or even multiple different ones). But having it as the first member is of course always safe.

Comment: Thanks @FelixG for the very good comment and point, to learn more about this https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/DataStructures/linux-datastructures-1.html, such "magic" is helped by the following macro "#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)"

Comment: This is phenomenal! All day sitting without result. Asked on SOF and immediately the answer))